# Field Theory, Factor Ring, Polynomials

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, factorial

I have the following problems:

(1)
Let $g=X^2+\overline{4}$ and $h=X^2+\overline{2}$ be polynomials in $(\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}7)[X]$. $L$ and $K$ are the splitting fields of $g$ and $h$ over $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}7$.

Find a field isomorphism
$$ \phi \colon \  L \longrightarrow K$$ 
an proove it is one.

(2)
Furthermore I have to show, that the splitting fields $L$ of $X^2-2$ and $K$ of $X^2-3$ (over $\mathbb{Q}$) are not isomorph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember the splitting fields of a quadratic polynomial $f(t)$ over a field $F$ all look like $\{ax+b\mid a,b\in F\}$ for some $x$ satisfying $f(x)=0$.  The fact that $f(x)=0$ shows you how to multiply two elements of the form $ax+b$ to obtain another element of the same form.

Hints:

(1) In $L$, we have an element $\alpha$ whose square is $-4\equiv 3\pmod 7$, and in $K$ we have an element $\beta$ whose square is $-2\equiv 5\pmod 7$.  What is the square of $2\alpha$ in $L$?

(2) If the splitting fields were isomorphic, then the splitting field of $X^2-3$ would have an element whose square is $2$.

Comment: Thank you for your hints. If the square of $\alpha$ is $-4\equiv 3\pmod 7$, then the square of $2\alpha$ is  $-2\equiv 5\pmod 7$, so maybe I can define $\overline{\alpha} \mapsto \overline{2\alpha}$. As an isomorphism I would define the identity $\psi \colon \mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}7 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}7 \colon \overline{k} \mapsto \overline{k}$. And with the extension theorem I would define the isomorphism $\phi \colon L \rightarrow K$ with $\phi|_{\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}7}=\psi$ and $\overline{\alpha} \mapsto \overline{2\alpha}$.

Comment: @user136068: Close.  We want to define a map from $L$ to $K$, not from $L$ to $L$.  The element $2\alpha$ is in $L$, but it has similar properties as the element $\beta$ in $K$, so we want to define a map that sends $2\alpha$ to $\beta$.  Since the map is linear, what would this mean for $\alpha$?

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure, if I can follow. If we define $\phi(\overline{2\alpha})=\overline{\beta}$, we can write $\phi(\overline{2\alpha})=\overline{2}\cdot\phi(\overline{\alpha})$ because $\phi$ is multiplicative.

Comment: @math_space: Exactly.  So then $\phi(\alpha)=\beta/2$.  This completely defines the map.  You should check that it is indeed a field isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you. But I have two more questions: $\beta$ is in $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}7$. But is the fraction $\beta/2$ well posed? I only know that addition and multiplication are well posed. And: We took the element $\alpha$ and only if we define $\phi(\alpha)=\beta/2$ the whole isomorphism is defined. But is this $\alpha$ unique? What's if we have other zeroes of our polynomial g?

Comment: @math_space: $\beta$ is not in $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$, because there is no element in $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$ whose square is $5$.  $\beta$ is in $K$, which is a field extension of $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$.  Since $K$ is a field of characteristic not $2$, we can divide by $2$.  To your other question, the field isomorphism we've defined is not unique.  There is another sending $-\alpha$ to $\beta/2$.  As you note, this is because $-\alpha$ is also a root of $g$ if $\alpha$ is.  And again, $-\alpha\ne\alpha$ because $2\ne 0$ in $L$.

Comment: Thx, I think, now I'm understanding. I forgot that $\beta$ is in $K$ and we don't know, what $K$ looks like. So we found two different isomorphisms. And my argument, that $\phi|_{\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}7}=\psi$ was correct?

Comment: And I'm sorry that I've never heared someting about "charakteristic". So I have no idea why $K$ and $L$ have not characteristic $2$ and what this means.

Comment: @math_space: Any field isomorphism will fix $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$, so that $\phi|_{\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}}=\psi$.  Also, every field has a characteristic, which is either $0$ or a prime number $p$.  The characteristic of any field extension of $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$ is $7$.  As long as the characteristic is not $2$, we are allowed to divide by $2$.  You can read about this [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FieldCharacteristic.html).  If you have further questions not specifically related to this question, you should probably ask a new question, as our chat is getting fairly long here.